# Как добавить задний фон в QWidget?

Tags: qt, qss

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Захотел сделать фон в QWidget. 
Добавил в stylesheet:

```
QWidget {
    background: url("./image/layer.png");
}
```

Получил тормоза. Загрузка ЦП 100 %. Как такое может быть?

Comment: А можно пример `layer.png` в вопрос? Можете его в редактор вопроса перетащить, либо скопировать в редакторе/браузере картинку и Ctrl+V вставить. Если картинку нельзя показывать, то опишите ее: размеры и вес

Comment: Че это нельзя ее показывать. Приложил фото. У меня процессор ARM одно ядро 454 МГц. НЕ i7.

Comment: Градиентная картинка для вашего проца, видимо, тяжеловата. Попробуйте обычную, однотонную

Comment: И нельзя это не как оптимизировать?

Comment: Для начала уменьшите качество картинки, скажем не 24bpp, а 16, или даже 8, и так далее. В принципе, нет смысла фигачить на фон высокоточную картинку, тем более без какого-то аляповатого рисунка

Comment: еще один момент. попробуйте вместо картинки использовать штатный градиент. типа такого QWidget{
background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255));
}